# Multi Segments in one segment in a donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, donut-chart, sunburst-diagram

I am looking for Multi Segments in a single segment.

Each segment can have a different color scheme Category.

I am looking for something like this:

[Dounut chart that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdEPO.png)

I have tried googling around, I can't find any solution for multi segments in one segment.

btw I'm creating PowerBi Custom Visual.

Here is my code using d3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg></svg>
    </body>

    <script>
        // JSON data
        var nodeData = {
            "name": "TOPICS", "children": [{
                "name": "Active Members",
                "children": [{ "name": "Delta", "size": 230000 }, { "name": "United", "size": 400000 },{ "name": "American", "size": 750000 },{ "name": "Alaska", "size": 250000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "No of customers",
                "children": [{ "name": "Amex", "size": 204300 }, { "name": "Visa", "size": 300000 },{ "name": "Paypal", "size": 400000 },{ "name": "Others", "size": 120000 },{ "name": "Mastercard", "size": 110440 },{ "name": "Discover", "size": 400000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "No of claims Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Hospital 1", "size": 150000 }, { "name": "Hospital 2", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Hospital 3", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Hospital 4", "size": 500000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "no of amount paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Pizza", "size": 500000 }, { "name": "Burger", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Sandwich", "size": 450000 }, { "name": "Toast", "size": 250000 }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Medical Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Doctor 1", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Doctor 2", "size": 200000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "Pharmacy Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "CVS", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Walgreens", "size": 100000 }, { "name": "Walrmart", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Others", "size": 100000 }],
            }]
        };

        // Variables
        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var donutWidth = 25;

        // Create primary <g> element
        var g = d3.select('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        // Data strucure
        var partition = d3.partition()
            .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

        // Find data root
        var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
            .sum(function (d) { return d.size });

        // Size arcs
        partition(root);
        var arc = d3.arc()
            .startAngle(function (d) { return d.x0 })
            .endAngle(function (d) { return d.x1 })
            .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
            .outerRadius(radius)
            // .innerRadius(function (d) { return d.y0 })
            // .outerRadius(function (d) { return d.y1 })
            .padAngle(0.04);

        // Put it all together
        g.selectAll('path')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr("display", function (d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style('stroke', '#fff')
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name); });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make 2 updates to your code to achieve this.

1) Create a colour scale per topic, so that each child node gets a unique colour within its segment.

2) As the padding applies to every segment in the donut chart, you can create the illusion of gaps between the parent segments by inserting dummy data with a value, and then filling those segments with white.

```js
     
      
        var nodeData = {
            "name": "TOPICS", "children": [{
                "name": "Active Members",
                "children": [{ "name": "Delta", "size": 230000 }, { "name": "United", "size": 400000 },{ "name": "American", "size": 750000 },{ "name": "Alaska", "size": 250000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "No of customers",
                "children": [{ "name": "Amex", "size": 204300 }, { "name": "Visa", "size": 300000 },{ "name": "Paypal", "size": 400000 },{ "name": "Others", "size": 120000 },{ "name": "Mastercard", "size": 110440 },{ "name": "Discover", "size": 400000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "No of claims Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Hospital 1", "size": 150000 }, { "name": "Hospital 2", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Hospital 3", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Hospital 4", "size": 500000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "no of amount paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Pizza", "size": 500000 }, { "name": "Burger", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Sandwich", "size": 450000 }, { "name": "Toast", "size": 250000 }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Medical Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "Doctor 1", "size": 300000 }, { "name": "Doctor 2", "size": 200000 }]
            }, {
                "name": "Pharmacy Paid",
                "children": [{ "name": "CVS", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Walgreens", "size": 100000 }, { "name": "Walrmart", "size": 200000 }, { "name": "Others", "size": 100000 }],
            }]
        };

        // Variables
        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;
        //var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var donutWidth = 25;
       
       //CREATE A COLOUR SCALE PER CHILD TOPIC
       var colourScale = {}
       nodeData.children.forEach(function(d){
          colourScale[d.name] = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        })
     
        //INSERT DATA INTO ARRAY TO CREATE GAPS IN THE DONUT CHART
       var n = nodeData.children.length
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          var position = (i * 2) + 1
          var parentName = "Gap" + i
          var childName = "GapChild"
          var gapData = {"name": parentName, "children": [{"name": childName, "size": 100000}]} //choose a size which gives the desired gap
          nodeData.children.splice(position, 0, gapData)
        }
      
        // Create primary <g> element
        var g = d3.select('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        // Data strucure
        var partition = d3.partition()
            .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

        // Find data root
        var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
            .sum(function (d) { return d.size });

        // Size arcs
        partition(root);
        var arc = d3.arc()
            .startAngle(function (d) { return d.x0 })
            .endAngle(function (d) { return d.x1 })
            .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .padAngle(0.001);

        // Put it all together
        g.selectAll('path')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr("visibility", function (d) { return d.depth == 2 ? "visible" : "hidden"; })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style('stroke', '#fff')
            .style("fill", function (d) {
        // if the data is for "gap" child element or a parent node, then fill with white, else fill with categorical colour
             if (d.data.name == "GapChild") {
                   return "white"
                } else if (d.children) {
                   return "white"
                } else {
                   return colourScale[d.parent.data.name](d.data.name); 
                }
               
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<body>
 <svg></svg>
 </body>
```

Comment: I also want labelings for the main categories and children can do this for me it would be more helpful. @tom-shanley